# How to Refresh the window completely using javascript from Console App ~ Publisher action in Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I have been trying this from quite sometime now and not able to get around this problem.

I already used `window.top.location.href` and set it as the URL. But this opens the page in a new console tab.

How to refresh the complete page so that all primary tabs and subtabs are refreshed ?